# How can I access a data from another object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to access `availJobs` in `jobs.scan` object but I couldn't. It is not defined in `jobs.attack`. What can I do to access the part of `jobs.scan` in other objects?

```
var jobs = new Array();

jobs.scan = function() {
    var availJobs = new Array();
    var jobContents = dom.get("app8743457343_content");
    var boldthreads = jobContents.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for(var i = 0; i < boldthreads.length; i++) {
        if(boldthreads[i].style.color == 'silver') {
            availJobs.push(boldthreads[i].textContent);
        }
    }
    return availJobs;
}

jobs.attack = function() {
    jobs.scan();
    alert(jobs.availJobs[0]);
}

jobs.attack();
```

`availJobs[0]` in `jobs.attack` doesn't work. It's `undefined`. How can I set the `availJobs` as public and can be accessed in other objects?

Thanks for all the help!!
Here's the code that I put:

```
var jobs = {
    availJobs: new Array(),
    scan: function() {
        var jobContents = dom.get("app8743457343_content");
        var boldthreads = jobContents.getElementsByTagName('b');
        for(var i = 0; i < boldthreads.length; i++) {
            if(boldthreads[i].style.color == 'silver') {
                this.availJobs.push(boldthreads[i].textContent);
            }
        }
    },
    attack: function() {
        this.scan();
        alert(this.availJobs[0]);
    },
};

jobs.attack();
```

This code is definitely more elegant don't you think? I used this and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{}` is used to initialize an object and Array to initialize an array.

```
var jobs = {
    availJobs : new Array()
}

jobs.scan = function() {
    var jobContents = dom.get("app8743457343_content");
    var boldthreads = jobContents.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for(var i = 0; i < boldthreads.length; i++) {
        if(boldthreads[i].style.color == 'silver') {
            availJobs.push(boldthreads[i].textContent);
        }
    }
    return availJobs;
}
```

In a `{}` declaration, you can put add multiple members to your object if you separe them with a comma `,` :

```
var jobs = {
    availJobs : new Array(),
    anotherMember : null,
    anotherArray : new Array(),
    aFunction = function() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but I'm pretty sure you need to declare availJobs outside of the function itself, IE: `jobs.availJobs = new Array();`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. `jobs.scan` is one function, `jobs.attack` is another. `availJobs` is a local variable defined in `jobs.scan`. You can't access local variables of one function from another.

Even more, `availJobs` doesn't exist by the time you try to access it, because jobs.scan is already finished.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the availJobs array and jobs should be an object.

```
var jobs = {}

jobs.availJobs = []

jobs.scan = function() {
    var availJobs = new Array();
    var jobContents = dom.get("app8743457343_content");
    var boldthreads = jobContents.getElementsByTagName('b');
    for(var i = 0; i < boldthreads.length; i++) {
        if(boldthreads[i].style.color == 'silver') {
            availJobs.push(boldthreads[i].textContent);
        }
    }
    return availJobs;
}

jobs.attack = function() {
    jobs.scan();
    alert(jobs.availJobs[0]);
}

jobs.attack();
```